# EF7 Database.EnsureCreated() ArgumentException parameter not valid multipleactiverecordsets

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am building a webbapplication to learn ASP.NET 5. I am using:

Visual Studio 2015 Community

ASP.NET 5 RC1

MVC 6

Entity Framework 7

The problem is that after creating my dbcontext to map entities to DB the application is unable to start due to an argumentexception. See below and note additional information that the parameter is not valid (Nyckelordet stöds inte): multipleactiverecordsets. How do I resolve this issue?

The project is able to run when I comment the following to what is presented later on:

AppController.cs

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //var textposts = _context.Textposts.OrderBy(t => t.UserName).ToList(); //here
        //return View(textposts); //here
        return View();
    }
```

ProjectContext.cs

```
    public class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {

    public ProjectContext()
    {
        //Create the database and execute migrations
        //Database.EnsureCreated(); //here
        //Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Below information about the problem and code snippets are presented.

[Error. EF7 DB argumentexception multipleactiverecordsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbPgt.png)

I have a DB ready and made an initial migration (a folder for migrations was created and cs files to the folder when using the "dnx ef migrations add InitialDatabase")

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ProjectContext>();
```

project.json

```
{
  "webroot":  "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

ProjectContext.cs

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{

    public ProjectContext()
    {
        //Create the database and execute migrations
        //Database.EnsureCreated();
        //Database.Migrate();
    }

    public DbSet<Textpost> Textposts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:ProjectContextConnection"];
        //Optionsbuilder exposes the entities, using SQL Server.
        //Other types of db servers could be shown here if configured, such as MongoDB
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

}

AppController.cs

```
public class AppController : Controller
{
    private IMailService _mailService;
    private ProjectContext _context;

    public AppController(IMailService service, ProjectContext context)
    {
        _mailService = service;
        _context = context;
    }

    //The request is called Index. No id parameter in here yet -> app/index/id
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var textposts = _context.Textposts.OrderBy(t => t.UserName).ToList();
        return View(textposts);
        //return View();
    }
```

Also, the phrase "parameter not valid (Nyckelordet stöds inte): multipleactiverecordsets" shows when I try to add a new migration using dnx ef command tool.

[dnx ef migration add SecondMigration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wkJs.png)

EDIT:
My connection string in config.json

```
  "Data": {
    "ProjectContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Database=ProjectDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveRecordSets=True;"
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - pls show us your connection string

Answer (score 2):

ErikEJ was on to something by asking about the connection string.

After following a tutorial on how to set up the database and connections string, I now changed the last part of the string from MultipleActiveRecordSets to MultipleActiveResultSets. Perhaps the first notation comes from a previous version that now is not supported. It is working now, thanks for the tip and warm welcome!